# Quartz.net config works with XML, but throws db connection error when configuring with code

Tags: quartz.net

Here is my XML config section for Quartz:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="DefaultQuartzScheduler" />
<!--Configure Thread Pool -->
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
<!--Configure Job Store -->
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="[Quartz].QRTZ_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=xxxxxx; Integrated Security=True;" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
```

This config file currently works when using the StdSchedulerFactory like this:

```
var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
factory.Initialize();
```

I'm currently trying to take the existing configuration and load ALL config values in code. I'm using the NameValueCollection overload can be passed to StdSchedulerFactory(config).

Here is my code:

```
var quartzConfig = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "DefaultQuartzScheduler" }, 
    { "quartz.threadPool.type", "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" }, 
    { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1" }, 
    { "quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "Normal" }, 
    { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "6000" }, 
    { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" }, 
    { "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" }, 
    { "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "[Quartz].QRTZ_" }, 
    { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "myDS" }, 
    { "quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString", "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=xxxxxx; Integrated Security=True;" }, 
    { "quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider", "SqlServer-20" }
}

var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(quartzConfig);
factory.Initialize();
```

In my app.config file, I have REMOVED the  section assuming that all the config values are now being loaded by my code above.

Yet, when I go to run the application, I keep getting:

```
Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS'
```

Not too sure if I'm doing this right. When loading the config values with code instead of xml in the app.config, do I leave the emtpy  section there? Do I remove it entirely?

Not too sure what I'm doing, but I cannot get Quartz to find the connection string this way.

Answer (score 2):

wow, it came down to a string formatting issue.

For XML config, this was fine:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=xxxxxx; Integrated Security=True;" />
```

For the code config, I had to add an extra "\" in front of "\v11.0":

```
{ "quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString", "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0; Initial Catalog=IXRS_123456; Integrated Security=True;" }
```

Comment: Holy crap. I'm glad I stumbled across this post. I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now, was driving me nuts! Thanks a bunch for posting your answer here after you figured it out.